Why doesn't line height change?
I have the following compose function:
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test(){
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(
            text = "hello1",
            lineHeight = TextUnit(50f, TextUnitType.Sp)
        )
        Text(
            text = "hello2",
            lineHeight = TextUnit(500f, TextUnitType.Sp)
        )
    }

}

I expect to see 2 texts with different line height, but for some reason none of them have any height changes:

Why?

Line height will only make difference if the same text it was given to returns to the line like try adding \n in the middle of those examples an you will see the difference
Example :
If the text is "hello1 \n world"
It will look like that
Hello1
(Line height you specified
will make difference here)
World

MohamedMab's answer is right up to certain version of compose bom. If i try on 2023.08.00 version, line height actually depends on if there is a next line character. But then i upgraded my compose bom version to 2024.05.00 and now lineHeight parameter just puts empty space above and below the text, regardless of a next line character presence.
